# How to reset user select option from configurable widget (ios14)

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios14, widgetkit

I'm making a configurable widget

user can select an option from one of widgets

[image]

and some point I want to reset that option. (for example, if user logout, user's option need to be reset.)

I used `func defaultMyType(for intent: MyTypeIntent) -> MyType?` but it does not work.

How can I reset user's option?

thanks

Comment: This is related: [How to reset intent extension configurations in WidgetKit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63764083/8697793)

Comment: @pawello2222 unfortunately I don't use core data. I always wonder about apple document's useless...

Comment: @WoffOVkee, did you found the solution. I need that badly.

Comment: @elk_cloner no I didn't find. because widget can not find data without user info anyway it shows kinda empty ui (it's indendied). so I decided option leave previous user selected...